# setTimeout only looping once, not submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, settimeout

I was trying to help someone with a jQuery submit form. He was submitting, and trying to output some text to a form. However because of submitting; his script was halted before it displayed everything. I was able to make a script to display his text before it submitted, but I wanted to get more technical, and have it WAIT to submit so that the response was able to be read first. However, my `setTimeout()` is not looping, as well as the form will not submit after `preventDefault()` Any ideas as to what the issue is?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUUs7/31/)** (Original broken [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUUs7/))

Current test code. I realize it's a lot longer then it should be, but I've broken this code down 5 times now in different method, this being the most basic and showing me all the steps... yet nothing.

The main issue is it never enters the condition `if ( run === 1 ) {` as if the setTimeout doesn't even loop once.

I am also able to get the script to run when using buttons, instead of submit buttons like **[the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/G5vFB/44/)**

**Update:** The code has been revised, and now sends the submit after X seconds like it should.

```
 var formElm = $('#replyform');
     positive = $('input[value="Positive"]'),
     negative = $('input[value="Negative"]'),
     response = $('#txt1'),
     run = 0,
     submitnum = 0;

positive.click(function(e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitnum = 1;
    setInterval(submits, 1000);
});

negative.click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     submitnum = 2;
     setInterval(submits, 1000);

});

function submits() {
    if ( submitnum === 1) {
        submitForm(positive);
    } else if ( submitnum === 2 ) {
        submitForm(negative);
    }
}


function submitForm (e) {
    response.val(e.attr('name') + ' was clicked.');
    if ( run === 1 ) {
        alert('About to submit!');
        e.get(0).form.submit();
    }
    run++
    alert(run);
}
```

**If you are interested in the working condensed code:**

This relies on Class Names set for the buttons, as well as the type being button, and not submit.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var buttonName = $(this).attr('name'),
    elm = $(this);
    $('#txt1').val( buttonName + ' was clicked.' ); // Add response
    setTimeout(function(){               
         elm.get(0).form.submit(); // Submit form           
    }, 5000); // After 5 seconds
 });
```

Comment: Looks like functions called by timeouts don't have a new [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout). `setTimeout()` executes a function after a delay _once_, if you need a "loop", you probably need to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval).

Comment: @Teemu Thanks, that does the trick on the loop perfectly but still not submitting the form. I added `e.form.submit()` which threw a error as suggested below. I need it to send the value of the button clicked, which won't be the case if I submit the main form correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
function submitForm (e) {
    response.val(e.attr('name') + ' was clicked.');
    if ( run === 1 ) {
        alert('About to submit!');
        e.get(0).form.submit();
    }
    run++
    alert(run);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZUUs7/11/

Comment: One of the main issues is it never enters that condition `run === 1` as if the Timeout doesn't loop.

Comment: ALso the added `.form.` throws a: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined` where as without throws no error, but doesn't submit.

Comment: I made a mistake. Because e is jQuery object you should use e.get(0).form.submit()

Comment: It does work that way, though interestingly enough it doesn't allow time to alert that it is about to submit. or event the integer alert.

Comment: Can you take a chance to cancel real submitting form after click submit button?

Comment: Isn't that what I have with `e.preventDefault();` ? The response text is intended to be read before submitting the form (as it does now) just interesting how it kills alerts. But that shouldn't be a issue in implementation.

Comment: Nevermind, seems my browser was preventing further popups due to the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.post` to submit the form.

This way you can attach a success function that runs when the form has been submitted successfully.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUUs7/27/

Comment: The method used here would take the user elsewhere, it'd be redundant to have JS send them after a post call.

Comment: The expected behavior is to take the user elsewhere? Because an ajax post call wouldn't do that.

Comment: Which is why we aren't using ajax, or post... ? It's a basic submission to another page as shown in the exampled code.

Comment: oh my bad. so now everything works except that the alerts aren't coming?

Comment: All is good now. My browser disabled alerts because of the loop.